# How to stop the animation halfway and transit in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this structure of animations:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv0fq.png

The idle state runs in a loop until the user presses "space",then parameter named "Jump" becomes true and the transition between idle and Jump becomes active.But before it becomes active user has to wait for "idle" to finish.How can i make it so when user presses space,idle automatically stops and transits to Jump? I tried making 'animation' stop like this:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
            anim.Stop();
            animator.SetBool("Jump",true);
        }
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I warn you the jump is not that easy.
You will need to know if the player is on ground if you don't want your player to be able to jump in the air and many other things.

Anyway to your question.
To avoid exit time on animation you should uncheck the "Has exit time" value on the animator arrow between an animation and the other one.
Your current code just stop the animator but that's not what you really want... you want it to return to Idle.
The best thing you can do is:
- From "Any state" to "Jump" (you should create a blend tree between Jump and Fall)--->in the arrow uncheck "Has exit time" and set up a new Bool "JumpBool" (for example).

- From "Entry" to "Idle"
- From "Jump" to "Idle" when "JumpBool" is false.

In your code:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("space") && !OnGround()){
   animator.SetBool("JumpBool",true);
}
```

(you should create your OnGround method).

```
else if(OnGround()){
   animator.SetBool("JumpBool",false);
}
```

Of course this is almost pseudo-code. Like I said you should create a BlendTree for Jump and Fall where you should be able to tell if you need to play the jump animation of just the fall animation (maybe with a float depending on your corrent rigidbody .velocity.y speed).